# confusion in stability verifier command "isstable"

Tags: matlab

I m writing code to check the stability of two systems and i learn from output plots that one system is stable and other is not. But when i use command "isstable". It shows both systems to be stable

I have tried plotting output of both systems. here is actual code

```
clc
clear all
close all
t=0:0.1:10
x=cos(2*pi*t)
plot(t,x)
ylim([-2 2])
y1=x.^2
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,y1)
ylim([-0.5 1.5])
y2=t.*x
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,y2)
stable_of_y1=isstable(y1)
stable_of_y2=isstable(y2)
```

[image]

Comment: That function is to check stability  given a system model (transfer function).

Comment: To clarify more what Sardar is saying: the input of `isstable` should not be a vector, but a [dynamic system model](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/dynamic-system-models.html), which is a specific MATLAB variable type